# UIView from xib is blurred

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

Sorry guys, my mistake.

I was setting layer.shouldRasterize to YES.

This has been causing the issue. Thanks for the response.

I am facing a weird issue. I have a custom UIView, which has an associated xib file. Am using the following method to load the view from xib.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        Class class = [self class];
        NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass(class);
        NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];

        self = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

but the view being added in my View Controller is blurred.
[image]

Am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your code.

Comment: 1) I added a new UIView and set it to my custom class.
2) Then CustomView *ttView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
3) Set Frame.
4) Add it as a subview to app's rootViewController.

Comment: Let me know if u need any more info.

Comment: As per my understanding the way your adding is wrong. Your point 4 is I m not understanding why your adding to rootviewcontroller. Is your cutomeclass is viewcontroller class object?post your code for adding,set frame and adding view to rootviewcontroller

Comment: I'm not using xibs (prefer to setup views in code) but when using in code layout you must be aware of 2x 3x sizes (eg when you setCenter: -> it can be blurry). Maybe you did wrong constraints and on low resultion it works badly? Did you test it on iPhone 6+ simulator and is it blurry then?

Comment: Guys my mistake.

I have set layer.shouldRasterize to YES,

because of this the blur occurs. Thanks for the Response

Comment: Answer your own question then, don't edit the answer into the question. quedtions are "resolved" when they have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry guys, my mistake.

I was setting view's layer.shouldRasterize to YES.

This has been causing the issue. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a issue, may be its not blurred, you have applied images to all the buttons, the resolution is not appropriate i mean images are stretched so, apply 2x images to all. may be this could solve your problem.

Comment: Only the button background is an image. All others are native controls. UILabel and UITextView.

Comment: *this is not an issue* isn't a helpful answer to someone who took the trouble to post a question about their issue.